# Converting PHP To Rails -- Twilio Call Tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

After Michael Hartl's tutorial on rails, I'm trying to build a call tracking app, to learn more rails and Twilio.

So far I've managed to create --

- Authentication
- Integration With Stripe
- Every User who registers automatically gets a Twilio Subaccount
- Users Can Search for Phone Numbers, And Buy them

*(This has been done with 20 Stackoverflow questions in the last 5 days!)*

Now, What I would like to do is to actually create the functionality for recording call data via Twilio.

They have a php tutorial here : 
http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/call-tracking

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how I'm going to make this work. I.e What Combination of Controllers/Actions will I need to route calls through a twilio number, and receive the information?

So far, I have 3 models

**Plan Model**

```
#  name              :string(255)
#  max_phone_numbers :integer
#  max_minutes       :integer
#  price             :integer
has_many :users
```

**User Model**

```
#  name                  :string(255)
#  email                 :string(255)
#  twilio_account_sid    :string(255)
#  twilio_auth_token     :string(255)
#  plan_id               :integer
#  stripe_customer_token :string(255)
belongs_to :plan
has_many :phones
```

**Phone Model**

```
#  campaign_       :string(255)
#  twilio_number   :integer
#  original_number :integer
#  user_id
belongs_to :user
```

---

Now, I'm thinking of having a new model, called Phone_data. The Phone Model than has_many Phone_datas. I could than use the association to show data on a particular phone.

**Possible New Model: phone_data**

```
#Data that twilio can save to each phone(duration of call, etc )
#phone_id
#belongs_to phones
```

My question is, does the phone_data model make sense, and more importantly, how do you think the Controllers are going to look like, to achieve the functionality to

1. Lead dials a Twilio number and Twilio POSTs information to your application
2. Application saves Twilio call information to the proper phone_data association
3. The application sends TwiML instructions to Dial the original_number
4. Lead and agent have a conversation until one of them disconnects
5. Twilio requests the Dial action URL and sends information about the second call leg

Here's the code that they use for PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys at Twilio, especially Brian Levine, are amazing. Brian went ahead and explained this to me...by building a sample application! found here :

https://github.com/Beans0063/Twilio-Call-Tracking-Ruby